# MySQL - Join 2 Tables By Common ID

Tags: mysql, database, join, phpmyadmin

There is a similar question to this on S/O but it doesn't fit my need, This is not a duplicate.

My Scenario.

I have 2 tables. `Customers and Payments`(Self Explanatory)

I want create a "view" in PHPMyAdmin so I can view all this information together but I am really not sure how.

The columns in the table are `ID`.

How would I go about making this view? I really have no idea where to start (I'm into PHP but not SQL)

Comment: give schema of both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create view as below

```
Create view yourviewName AS
Select * from Customers join Payments on customers.ID = Payments.ID
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Il add this to my OneNote, Such a short statement. I guess its hard if you don't know it though :) I will accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry, It wouldn't let me first time as I needed to wait some minutes and I had to go out. Just accepted now :)

Comment: @GavW hey no problem. Was happy that it helped you. Have a good luck further.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only common column:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT * FROM Customers NATURAL JOIN Payments;
```